# Trying to input a lot of Data into mysqldb

Tags: python, mysql, database

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function

import pymysql.cursors

Journal=open('J_15April.txt')

jrn=Journal.read()

Zeile=jrn.split('14.04.2015')

conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root',passwd='',db='daten', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)


ean = int(row[0])
smr = char(row[1])
uhrzeit = char(row[2])


for line in Zeile:
cur = conn.cursor()
    if 'BOTTLE_ID' in line

        line2 = line.split(';')

        line3 = line2[0].strip(' BOTTLE_UNIQUE: BOTTLE_ID: 0')

        uhrzeit = (line3[:-4])

        if 'EAN' not in line:
            ean = 0

        else:
           ean = line2[7].strip('EAN: ')


        if ' SMR: 1;' in line:
            smr = ('gelesen')

        else:
            smr = ('nicht gelesen')

        cur.execute("INSERT INTO lga (ean, smr, uhrzeit) VALUES  ('%s','%s','%s')%(ean, smr, uhrzeit)")
        cur.fetchall()




cur.close()
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Hi guys,

I'm currently trying to put a lot of data into a mysqldb. I wrote two separate programs, one is for filtering the important stuff out of a very long .txt and the other one inserts them in the database.

The actual problem now occured when I tried combine those two program to automatically read and insert the data. I think the structure of the shown program may be a little chaotic and that's the main reason why it is not working. I'm absolutely new to python and it was quite hard for me two make the two other programs work so please help me out.

If you are interested in the two single functions I can post them as well.

greetings

trbo

**Traceback**

So this would be the Traceback when i run the code:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\tristan.bonn\Desktop\Python\Verbindung mit mysql\Tabelle mit Daten füllen.2.py", line 17, in row = cur.fetchall()

File "C:\Users\tristan.bonn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 256, in fetchall self._check_executed()

File "C:\Users\tristan.bonn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 70, in _check_executed raise err.ProgrammingError("execute() first") pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: execute() first

Comment: Can you share the traceback when you run the code? This may help in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe to make everything more clear here are the two codes im currently trying to put together

```
from __future__ import print_function

import pymysql.cursors


conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root',passwd='',db='daten', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("INSERT INTO lga (ean, smr, uhrzeit) VALUES ('85479630','gelesen','17:40:34')")
row = cur.fetchall()



cur.close()
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

This is the first code, which connects to the database.

```
Journal=open('J_15April.txt')

jrn=Journal.read()

Zeile=jrn.split('14.04.2015')

x = len (Zeile)

for line in Zeile:
    if 'BOTTLE_ID' in line:

        line2 = line.split(';')

        line3 = line2[0].strip(' BOTTLE_UNIQUE: BOTTLE_ID: 0')

        print (line3[:-4])

        if 'EAN' not in line:
            print ('keine EAN Vorhanden/Fehler')

        else:
            print(line2[7].strip('EAN: '))

        if ' SMR: 1;' in line:
            print ('gelesen')



        else:
            print ('nicht gelesen')
```

And this one reads the important data out of my .txt file

greetings

trbo